# .NET VB adding a session check to a compiled page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a .Net page that I want to add a session check to. If a user is not logged in, then kick them out.

I know absolutely nothing about .Net but I do know classic asp.

What I was planning on doing was creating a classic asp login page and then set the session when it's successfully logged in. On the .net page, I would like to check the session that was created and boot them out if it wasn't successfully logged in.

From what I could tell, everything has been compiled. I'm not sure what I can do on the page. Here's the code for the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ViewReport.aspx.vb" Inherits="ViewReport"%>
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CrystalWeb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="CrystalViewerForm" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:timer runat="server" ID="ReportRefreshTimer" Enabled="False"></asp:timer>
    <div>
        <CrystalWeb:CrystalReportViewer ID="RViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
    </div>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="RCSLink" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#BCC8DA" NavigateUrl="https://www.recrystallize.com" Target="_blank">ReCrystallize Server for Crystal Reports</asp:HyperLink>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you put that `e.Redirect` in the `Register` line? Is it correct??

Comment: that was a mistake... corrected it.

Comment: So you don't have the source for the application you want to add this check to?

Comment: no... i have 2 pages... the list page written in c# and the main page written in vb. I want to set the session in a new login page (.asp) and then make sure the c# and vb check for that variable